# How do you check if a nameserver responds to recursive queries?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am just curious if you could use dig to check if a certain nameserver responds to recursive queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `dig` and check the status of the `RD` and `RA` bits in the response.

By default `dig` will send a recursive query (`RD` set in the query header) unless you set the `+norecurse` command line flag.

If the server supports recursive queries the response will have the "recursion available" `RA` bit set in the response headers.

The `RA` bit is *the* diagnostic test for recursive query support.

Answer (score 14):

See if you can query it for a DNS entry for which it is not authoritative, e.g., try: `host www.cnn.com ns.example.com`, where ns.example.com is the name server you're testing.  If it doesn't respond to recursive queries, you will get a REFUSED.

```
$ host www.cnn.com. ns1.example.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.example.com
Address: 192.168.183.130#53
Aliases:

Host www.cnn.com not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

whereas a DNS server that does recursive queries:

```
$ host www.cnn.com. 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

www.cnn.com has address 157.166.255.18
www.cnn.com has address 157.166.255.19
www.cnn.com has address 157.166.226.25
www.cnn.com has address 157.166.226.26
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @cjc. I also figured out another method but using dig. Try to lookup a domain to a nameserver that is non-authorative to the domain. If it doesn't return anything, then it's not responding to recursive queries.

Comment: @Mikko, yes, both `dig` and `host` (and the now deprecated `nslookup`) are DNS query tools.  All of them are sufficient for determining whether a DNS server is allowing recursive queries from your IP address.

Comment: this is wrong - `REFUSED` is also the response code you get if you ask an authoritative name server for information about a domain for which it doesn't have a zone file.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, use an online checker such as:

http://www.intodns.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Alnitak's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/373017/1001806) a simple script can be written using the [dnspython](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module:

```py
import dns, dns.resolver

domain = "www.cnn.com"
nameserver_ip = "8.8.8.8"

message = dns.message.make_query(domain, rdtype=dns.rdatatype.A, ednsflags=dns.flags.RA)
resp = dns.query.udp(message, nameserver_ip)
if resp.rcode() != 0:
    print("Nameserver responds to recursive queries.")
```