# What are all the flags in a dig response?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

`dig` responses return flags in the comments section:

```
$ dig example.com +noall +comments

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> example.com +noall +comments
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29045
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

On the last line here, there are flags:

```
flags: qr rd ra;
```

What are all the possible flags that dig has?

Here's a list of the ones I've found so far:

- rd - [Recursion Desired](https://serverfault.com/a/373017/218198)
- ra - [Recursion Available](https://serverfault.com/a/373017/218198)
- aa - [Authoritative Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/355927/218198)
- qr - Query?
- cd - Checking Disabled (not sure what this means)
- others?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I am using [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) as source, keeping to the sequence from there, regardless if you already mentioned it in your question.

- QR specifies whether this message is a query (0), or a response (1)
- OPCODE A four bit field, only valid values: 0,1,2
- AA Authoritative Answer
- TC TrunCation (truncated due to length greater than that permitted on the
              transmission channel)
- RD Recursion Desired
- RA Recursion Available
- Z  Reserved for future use.  Must be zero

There were two more DNSSEC-related flags introduced in [RFC 4035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4035.txt):

- CD (Checking Disabled): indicates a security-aware resolver should
  disable signature validation (that is, not check DNSSEC records)
- AD (Authentic Data): indicates the resolver believes the responses to be authentic - that is, validated by DNSSEC

Answer (score 15):

From: http://www.perdisci.com/useful-links/dig-info

```
DIG response header:

Flags:
AA = Authoritative Answer

TC = Truncation

RD = Recursion Desired (set in a query and copied into the response if recursion is supported)

RA = Recursion Available (if set, denotes recursive query support is available)

AD = Authenticated Data (for DNSSEC only; indicates that the data was authenticated)

CD = Checking Disabled (DNSSEC only; disables checking at the receiving server)

Response code:

0 = NOERR, no error

1 = FORMERR, format error (unable to understand the query)

2 = SERVFAIL, name server problem

3= NXDOMAIN, domain name does not exist

4 = NOTIMPL, not implemented

5 = REFUSED (e.g., refused zone transfer requests)
```

Answer (score 2):

For more information read:

RFC1035 - 4.1.1. Header section format (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)

RFC6895 - 2. DNS Query/Response Headers (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6895)

Comment: I don't think pointing at RFC's is really helpful, at least not with at least a quick summary of the information that can be found there.

Comment: how about this link? it shows the flags with text and points to the RFCs too
https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-12